Is the third day timeframe of Jesus burial/resurrection required for salvation?
In 1 Corinthians 15:1-4, Paul states the Gospel that saves: that Jesus died for our sins, was buried, and rose again on the third day. I have heard multiple versions of this when people teach people how to be saved, often in these two ways:

believe Jesus died for your sins, was buried, and rose again so you could be saved (no mention of the third day, just that he rose again)
believe Jesus died for your sins and rose again so you could be saved.
Notice how the third day was not mentioned, nor the burial in the second one. Why are they omitted? If one believes in either of those two for salvation, are they still unsaved? Romans 6 seems to claim that Jesus was buried so we could be saved, too. Why would Jesus wanna make us believe in a timeframe to be saved? Yes, we should believe it, but do we have to believe the 3rd day part to BE saved?


There is no logic behind this presumption that the 3-day period is essential. It's a historical fact behind the Gospel msg. All one must do to be saved is believe him, that entails submission and complete trust and obedience.

There are two ways to take your question.

Did Jesus have to be raised specifically on the third for you to be saved?

Do you have to believe that Jesus rose on the third day in order to be saved?


The answer to the first question is YES. Why? Because Jesus (as recorded in the gospels) prophesied before his death that he would rise again on the third day. If it did not happen that way, then he would be proved a liar, and a liar is a sinner and cannot be the savior of mankind.
The answer to the second question is MAYBE. The thief on the cross did not have to believe that and he was saved. There are people who are inadequately taught about Jesus who believe the little they have been told and are saved.
However, the statement about the third day is part of the Apostles’ Creed, Nicene Creed of 325 AD and the Nicene Creed of 381 AD. It is also part of the Athanasian Creed. (Some websites leave it out, so be careful where you look.)
The creeds are important because most orthodox churches require a candidate for baptism or church membership to affirm one of those creeds. The creeds are the result of the church, led by the Holy Spirit, defining and defending the true faith. Many clauses were put in to refute certain ancient heresies.
Thus should a person, after having been confronted with the creed, reject any part of it, it shows a lack of trust in the body of Christ. They may be saved, but it shows a lack of trust. Certainly to accept the Bible as the written Word of God requires that you believe in the third day, as both Old Testament and New Testament prophecies are involved.


OP: In 1 Corinthians 15:1-4, Paul states the Gospel that saves: that Jesus died for our sins, was buried, and rose again on the third day.

Good question about what exactly is the Gospel?

For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures; And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures: 1 Cor 15:3-4

There are basically three parts to the whole gospel.
Christ died for our sins.
He was buried.
He rose again the third day.
Paul says this is all according to the scriptures.
How important is this?  Very, for Paul it is by which ye are saved.

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand; By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain. v 1-2

Christ died for our sins.
This had been prophesied since Genesis.
And then subsequently, including Isaiah.

Surely he hath borne our griefs, and carried our sorrows: yet we did esteem him stricken, smitten of God, and afflicted. But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities: the chastisement of our peace was upon him; and with his stripes we are healed. All we like sheep have gone astray; we have turned every one to his own way; and the LORD hath laid on him the iniquity of us all. ... Yet it pleased the LORD to bruise him; he hath put him to grief: when thou shalt make his soul an offering for sin, he shall see his seed, he shall prolong his days, and the pleasure of the LORD shall prosper in his hand. He [God] shall see of the travail of his [Christ] soul, and shall be satisfied: by his knowledge shall my righteous servant justify many; for he shall bear their iniquities. Isa 53:5-6, 10-11

The word "iniquity" means sin, a depraved action, a crime. (Gesenius)
"Justify" means to be righteous, straight. (Gesenius)
So, the this first part of the gospel is Christ bore our sins by the which God was satisfied and we may be righteous.  Between bearing sins and being justified are the other two pieces.
He was buried.
The swoon theory and the stolen body theory persist to this day, but no, the gospel account prophesied He was dead and buried.

And he made his grave with the wicked, and with the rich in his death; because he had done no violence, neither was any deceit in his mouth. Isa 53:9


But God will redeem my soul from the power of the grave: for he shall receive me. Selah. Psalm 49:15

A sin offering is wholly dead.
He rose again the third day.
This too is necessary.  Obviously, many people believe Jesus existed, but was simply a man, simply a prophet, or simply something worse.  But rising from the dead is simply something else.
Like the other two beliefs, this third of three is also prophesied.

I will ransom them from the power of the grave; I will redeem them from death: O death, I will be thy plagues; O grave, I will be thy destruction: repentance shall be hid from mine eyes. Hos 13:14


Now the LORD had prepared a great fish to swallow up Jonah. And Jonah was in the belly of the fish three days and three nights. Jon 1:3

Conclusion
Without each part of the triad, we lose something that is the gospel.
Christ died for our sins.  Once.  Never to be repeated.

For in that he died, he died unto sin once: but in that he liveth, he liveth unto God. Rom 6:10

He was buried.  He didn't faint or hide or something else.
He rose on the third day.
Can any part be removed, not believed, and still be saved?  Which part is unnecessary?  Died for our sins, was buried, rose on the third day.  Each must be believed as prophesied.
